# Checkout redirecting to the cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart

Without changing anything my checkout now redirects to the cart page.

It happens after selecting the payment method. When i click on the **order now** button and it redirects me to the cart .

I have the following settings at my admin panel

```
in system -> sales -> checkout "allow guest checkout" set to "yes"
```

I don't know why it happens and the strange thing it is that the order is taken by Magento, but the order mail it is not sent.

Do you know why it would happen something like that? the logs do not tell anything about that?

---

this is the system.log

```
2017-05-10T08:25:40+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: type_product  in /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/local/Magentothem/Ajaxcartsuper/controllers/AjaxcartController.php on line 26
2017-05-10T08:29:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Import/Model.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2017-05-10T08:29:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Import/Model.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/local:/home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/community:/home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/core:/home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/lib:.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php')  in /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

and this is exception.log

```
    #0 /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Tipo blocco non...')
```

## 1 /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('relatedslider/p...', Array)

## 2 /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('relatedslider/p...', 'magentothem_rel...')

## 3 /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('relatedslider/p...', 'magentothem_rel...')

## 4 /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))

## 5 /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))

## 6 /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()

## 7 /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()

## 8 /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/local/Magentothem/Ajaxcartsuper/controllers/AjaxcartController.php(63): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()

## 9 /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Magentothem_Ajaxcartsuper_AjaxcartController->addAction()

## 10 /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')

## 11 /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

## 12 /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

## 13 /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

## 14 /home/max3322/public_html/ecommerce/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')

## 15 {main}

Comment: what do you have in System -> Sales -> Checkout "Require Customer To Be Logged In To Checkout"

Comment: I have in system -> sales -> checkout "allow guest checkout" set to "yes"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some days ago. I had an echo "." under index.php. 
Can you check if you have something in your index.php that is unnecessary ?

Refer to Magento index

[https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/index.php](http://index.php)

If it is not relating to this, set Magento to developer mode, by adding this code in index.php

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Check your logs under var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log if there is any error relating to that.